# Gathering proper onScroll data to trigger AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

I am calling an AJAX function on scroll with this:

```
// Collecting scroll info
$('.overthrow').each(function() {

  var self = this;
  var path2root = ".";
  var subcategoryId = $(this).attr('data-subcategoryId');
  var page = 1;

  $(this).bind('scroll', function() { 

    var scrollAmount = $(self).scrollLeft();
    var documentWidth = $(self).data('currentElementPosition') || $(document).width();
    var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentWidth) * 100;

    if (scrollPercent > 80) { 

      page++;

      console.log("process.php?subcategoryId=" + subcategoryId + "&page=" + page);

      // AJAX function for processing JSON
      $.ajax({
        url: "process.php?subcategoryId=" + subcategoryId + "&page=" + page,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          for(i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
            var articleId = data[i].articleResult.articleId;
            var title = data[i].articleResult.title;
            var subhead = data[i].articleResult.subhead;
            var image = data[i].articleResult.image;
            var response = "<td><div class='articleResult'><a href='" + path2root + "/article/article.php?articleId=" + articleId + "'><img src='" + image + "' width='120'/></a><br><h3><a href='" + path2root + "/article/article.php?articleId=" + articleId + "'>" + title.substring(0,25) + "</a></h3></div></td>";

            var appendedData = $(self).find("table tbody tr td:last-child").after(response).fadeIn('slow');
            $(self).data('currentElementPosition', appendedData.position().left);
          };
        }
      });
    };
  });
});
```

My problem is once the first response is appended to the content and I begin to scroll past 80% into the new results, each pixel I scroll calls the same AJAX function again & again, rather than waiting for the user to scroll the 80% width of the new window size.  Effectively making an AJAX call for each pixel scrolled past 80%.

Is an `if` statement the wrong route to go with something like this?  Should I be providing some type of callback to dynamically drive the integers that trigger the AJAX function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to save a reference to whatever you append to the DOM as a result of your AJAX call, get its position, and compare your scroll position to that.  In other words, assuming that in your example above, $(this) is the parent container in which all data returned via AJAX is inserted into, you could do something like this:

```
$(this).scroll(function () {
               var scrollAmount = $(this).scrollLeft();
               var documentWidth = $(this).data('currentElementPosition') || $(document).width()
               var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentWidth ) * 100;
                  if (scrollPercent > 80) { 
                      // AJAX function success
                          var appendedData = $(data_returned_from_ajax_call).appendTo($(this))
                          $(this).data('currentElementPosition', appendedData.position().left)
                     };
                  });
}
```

Just an FYI, an important thing to note is that jQuery's .offset() method will give you the position of the element relative to the document, while .position() will give you the position relative to its parent container.

Comment: This seems to be an interesting solution.  Been working with it for the last hour but hitting the end of the day, so I will jump back on it later or tomorrow and report back my results. +1 for now

Comment: great to hear!  let me know if there is anything I can do to help you out.

Comment: one thing that I noticed in looking over my code sample again is that you may actually lose the intended scope of $(this) within your AJAX success function.  I don't remember off the top of my head if that's the case though.  If you find that to be a problem, you can just save a variable anywhere in the scroll callback (e.g. right above var scrollAmount = ...) like so: var self = this  Then, from within your AJAX success function you can reference $(self).data('currentElementPosition', appendedData.position().left) to achieve the appropriate scope

Comment: Hey thanks so much!  I went ahead and plopped in my entire snippet of code in regards to the discussed functionality (was trying to keep it short and sweet).  I had already been using the `var self - this;` method as well :)  In regards to your suggested edits, I am noticing smoother behavior with your method, however I am still getting numerous AJAX calls per pixel during and after the initial load.  I was trying to set a `.bind()` on scroll, and `.unbind()` in my callback, but I keep getting stuck...

Comment: where you set var appendedData = ..., the right hand side of that expression is returning $(self), not `response`. so in the next line, when you set currentElementPosition, you're setting it to the left offset of $(self), not `response`. try this syntax instead var appendedData = $(response).appendTo($(self).find("table tbody tr td:last-child")).fadeIn('slow'); appendTo() will return `response`.  Also note that putting .fadeIn() at the end of the method chain after you've already appended something to the DOM won't fade it in, 'cause append automatically makes it visible.

Comment: Great, thank you for the pointers.  I had to go with `insertAfter` rather than `append` since `append` was placing the loaded `td`'s inside of the `td:last-child` rather than after, thus breaking my design.  This method seems to work just fine.  I still have some kinks to iron out, but I will go ahead and accept your answer.  Thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery's [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind it once, then in the success callback for your ajax rebind it (or anywhere after that)